# UIElement return empty text

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I'm writing software that needs to intercept an `AutomationElement` of an application. This `AutomationElement` is defined within a `ListBox`. When I use inspect.exe to check how I can get the value, the respective `AutomationElement` has no children.

Here is the code I am using to attempt to get the `ListItem`:

```
AutomationElement desktop = AutomationElement.FromHandle (tskBarHwndTest);
AutomationElement dataGrid1 = desktop.FindFirst (System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition (AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "QueueListView"));
if (dataGrid1! = null)
{
    AutomationElementCollection lines1 = dataGrid1.FindAll (System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition (AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ListItem));
    GridPattern pattern = GetGridPattern (dataGrid1);
    AutomationElement tempElement = pattern.GetItem (0, 2)
}
```

[image: Screenshot Inspect]

Comment: Please read **[ask]** and then update the question with relevant information.  As it stands this question is of poor quality, which makes it difficult for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are looking for `"QueueListView"` but in the inspect.exe screenshot I do not see an `AutomationElement` that is a descendant of the desktop with a `AutomationId` like that.

I would suggest using `System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope.Children` for your `TreeScope` and stepping one element at a time. When using `Descendants` it will be very slow to find anything if your application is non-trivial.

Since I can't see all the values in inspect it would look something like this.

```
AutomationElement desktop = AutomationElement.RootElement;
AutomationElment mainWindow = desktop.FindFirst(System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "<Your Main Window Name>");
//... add code here to get from main window to where your screen shot starts
AutomationElement panello1 = mainWindow.FindAll(System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "pannello"))[2];
AutomationElement tabulazione = panello1.FindFirst(System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "tabulazione"));
AutomationElement panello2 = tabulazione.FindFirst(System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "panello"));
AutomationElement interazioniPersonali = panello2.FindFirst(System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Interazioni personali"));
AutomationElement elenco = interazioniPersonali.FindFirst(System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "elenco"));
AutomationElement voceDiElenco = interazioniPersonali.FindFirst(System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "voce di elenco"));
AutomationElement numero = voceDiElenco.FindAll(System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "testo"))[2];
//... in if you expand the selected AutomationElement in your screenshot there should be a text element that contains the text you want to get
```

This can definitely be refined but this is just based on what I can see in the screen shot.